# Coordinates of Basis For Hermite Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let n = 2. Show that the following Hermite polynomials

$H_0(t) = 1$,

$H_1(t) = 2t$,

$H_2(t) = 4t^2 − 2$,

form a basis of $P_2$.

2) What are the coordinates of $H_0, H_1, H_2$ in the basis {$H_0, H_1, H_2$}? And in the basis {$1, t, t^2$}?

For part two, is this thinking terribly incorrect: if we have the basis {$ 1, 2t, 4t^2-2$} and we want to express the coordinates of $H_0, H_1, H_2$, would it be: ($1, 1, 1$)?

And to express $H_0, H_1, H_2$ in {$1, t, t^2$} , (1, 2, 4)? I would appreciate any assistance in helping me figure out how to think about this. I do think I am off-base (..ha). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_1=1, a_2=t$ and $a_3=t^2$. $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ form a basis of $P_2$. Let us assign vectors $v_1=[1,0,0]^T,v_2=[0,1,0]^T$ and $v_3=[0,0,1]^T$ to $a_1$,$a_2$ and $a_3$. Note that any polynomial $a+bt+ct^2$ in $P_2$ can then be expressed in vector notation as $av_1+bv_2+cv_3 = [a,b,c]^T$.

To show that $\{H_1,H_2,H_3\}$ also form a basis of $P_2$ one must show that the corresponding vectors are linearly independent. The vectors corresponding to $H_1,H_2$ and $H_3$ are $v_1,2v_2$ and $4v_3-2v_1$, respectively. It is easy to show that they are indeed independent using the definition.

If the chosen basis is $\{H_0,H_1,H_3\}$ then the coordinates of $H_1,H_2$ and $H_3$ are $e_1,e_2$ and $e_3$, respectively. If the chosen basis is $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ then the coordinates become (can you see what they will be from above ?).